# What is the best way to duplicate a calculation in Ruby & JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ruby, json, function

I have a Ruby on Rails application and I need to duplicate some computations in both Ruby and JavaScript.  Ruby is used in the server side but I also need to compute a students grade on the browser using JavaScript.

My first thought is to build up a JavaScript function using strings, convert it to JSON, ship it to the browser where it is decoded and used as a normal JavaScript function.  Does this sound workable to you?  I've tried something simple like

```
def letterGradeCalc
  "function calcLetterGrade(score) {
    if( score >= 90 ) { return 'A'; }
    else if( score >= 80 ) { return 'B'; }
    else if( score >= 0 ) { return 'F'; }
    else return '';
  }".to_json
end
```

but it is not a valid JavaScript function when the browser gets it.  It kinda looks like one but it has double quotes around it.

Am I barking up the wrong tree here?  I get the feeling that there is some insanely easy way to do this and but I'm completely missing it.  :)

Comment: I agree with Marc that this seems kind of like spinning your wheels. But to get a function, you just have to eval the received string in your Javascript.

Comment: Ah ha, JavaScript eval works great.  It turns out that you can use eval to not only return data but to build functions from strings.  It's kinda clunky and not at all Rubyish but it works.  Thanx!

Comment: if you have a rails server, why can't you write it in ruby on the server side, and just call it on the client side?

Answer (score 5):

For something trivially simple like that, I'd suggest writing a pure JS file with the function and including it.  Generating JS from ruby for this sounds like severe overkill.  Then write the same function in Ruby.

If it's  a moderately complex algorithm, I'd suggest only writing it in Ruby, and making a web service to call from JS.

Edit, adding code that got mungled in my comment below:

```
function calcLetterGrade(score, lowCutoff, hiCutoff) 
{ 
  if( score >= hiCutoff ) { return 'A'; } 
  else if( score >= lowCutoff ) { return 'B'; } 
  else if( score >= 0 ) { return 'F'; } 
  else return ''; 
}
```

Comment: Good suggestion.  The function is generally not complex (if..then) but it is built using user input.  Therefor I don't think I can construct the function before hand.  :(

Comment: Build using user input?  Sounds like those are just parameters to me.

function calcLetterGrade(score, lowCutoff, hiCutoff) {
    if( score >= hiCutoff ) { return 'A'; }
    else if( score < lowCutoff ) { return 'B'; }
    else if( score >= 0 ) { return 'F'; }
    else return '';
  }

Answer (score 2):

Make it an AJAX call to the web server from JavaScript, if it's not something that needs to be done quickly. With Rails, just call

```
remote_function :url    => remote_request_url,
                :update => dom_id_to_update
```

And have it render the result in the controller method as text.

Comment: Another good suggestion, but I really need the UI to update quickly.  Since the user could be entering information pretty fast I think a call would overwhelm my system.